# Excel VBA Copy, Paste, Insert variable rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA. I'm trying to copy rows with data from 1 workbook and insert it to another. The source has variable # of rows. The target has only 10 available rows followed by Merged cells.

My goal is: Count source rows, subtract 10 from it and the result would be the number of rows to be inserted at the target workbook prior to paste.

Example: 32 source rows (varies) - 10 target rows (fixed) = 22 rows to be inserted in the target WB pushing the merged cells down. If the result is <=10, just paste without inserting.

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: CallumDA solved it yesterday! I only had to modify last line! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destinationRange As Range
    Dim rowsToInsert As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set sourceRange = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set destinationRange = Workbooks("SomeBook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    rowsToInsert = Application.Max(sourceRange.Rows.Count - 10, 0)

    If rowsToInsert > 0 Then destinationRange.Resize(rowsToInsert, 1).EntireRow.Insert

    sourceRange.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destinationRange
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Couldn't have done it without your help! Why "sourceRange.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destinationRange" gave an error, I don't know... But I found a Code to select to last row, copy & paste.